# socket connection lost using select function

Tags: sockets, select, server

I'm newbee in socket program.
I made my server program with good sample program using select function.

It works well about 20,000 connections over.
But, in some case, connection accept twice consequence without
receive data from first socket.
Only data received from second socket connection.
After that, first socket resource cannot release.
FD_SET and FD_ISSET are not working with first socket in case of consequence accept I think.

Working clients are 6.

Before this situation,
accept, receive data, and close socket, accept, rcv
data, close, ...

In case, accept,
accept, receive data from second socket, and close second socket.
Lost first socket connection.

After that, accept function assign second socket descriptor.

What is problem?
How can release fisrt socket?

BR
Paul

Comment: This is clearly due to a bug in your code, but we can’t see it. Please show the actual code you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

My code is as follow:

```
while(1) 
    {
    //clear the socket set
    FD_ZERO (&readfds);

    //add master socket to set
    FD_SET (sever_socket, &readfds);
    max_sd = sever_socket;

    //add child sockets to set
    for ( i = 0 ; i < MAX_CLIENT ; i ++) 
        {
        //socket descriptor
        sd = client_socket [i];

        //if valid socket descriptor then add to read list
        if (sd > 0)
            {
            FD_SET( sd , &readfds);
            }

        //highest file descriptor number, need it for the select function
        if(sd > max_sd)
            {
            max_sd = sd;
            }
        }
    
    //wait for an activity on one of the sockets , timeout is NULL , so wait indefinitely
    activity = select ( max_sd + 1 , &readfds , NULL , NULL , NULL);
    if ((activity < 0) && (errno!=EINTR)) 
        {
        LOG_F (WARNING, "select error");
        }

    //If something happened on the master socket, then its an incoming connection
    if (FD_ISSET(sever_socket, &readfds)) 
        {
        if ((new_socket = accept (sever_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &address, (socklen_t*) &addrlen)) < 0)
            {
            perror("accept");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

        //inform user of socket number - used in send and receive commands
        LOG_F (INFO, "New connection, socket fd is %d, ip is : %s, port : %d", 
            new_socket, inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr), ntohs(address.sin_port));

        //add new socket to array of sockets
        for (i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENT; i++) 
            {           
            //if position is empty
            if( client_socket[i] == 0 )
                {
                client_socket[i] = new_socket;
                LOG_F (INFO, "Adding to list of sockets as %d" , i);
                break;
                }
            }
        }

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENT; i++) 
        {
        sd = client_socket[i];
             
        if (FD_ISSET (sd , &readfds)) 
            {
            memset (&rcvBuf, 0x00, sizeof(rcvBuf));
            if ((fp = fdopen (sd, "r")) == NULL) 
                {
                LOG_F (WARNING, "TCP_SOCKET FD_OPEN Error");
                close (sd);
                client_socket[i] = 0;
                }
            else 
                {
                ret = ioctl (sd, FIONREAD, &nread);
                
                if (nread == 0) 
                    {
                    fclose (fp);
                    close (sd);
                    client_socket[i] = 0;
                    LOG_F (WARNING, "Client disconnected(as %d, fd %d)", i, sd);                        
                    }
                else 
                    {
                    len = recv (sd, rcvBuf, nread, 0);
                    if (len > 0) 
                        {
                        LOG_F (INFO, "RECV size %d" , len);
                        ...
                        do_msg_handler ()
                     }
                 }
               ...
```